# How to get the event of clicking outside of QML GridView items in Qt6?

Tags: gridview, qml, qt6

I want to implement deselecting the current selection by clicking outside of the GridView items.
The following code works fine in Qt5. However,the click event cannot be obtained in Qt6.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
id: root
width: 640
height: 480
visible: true
title: qsTr("Hello World")

ListModel {
    id: listModel
     ListElement {
         name: "Jim Williams"
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "John Brown"
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "Bill Smyth"
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "Sam Wise"
     }
 }

GridView {
    id: gridView
    anchors.fill: parent
    cellWidth: 80
    cellHeight: 80
    model: listModel

    MouseArea {
         z: -1
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: {
             console.log("out clicked!")
             gridView.currentIndex = -1
        }
    }

     delegate: Item {
         id: wrapper
         width: gridView.cellWidth
         height: gridView.cellHeight

         Rectangle {
             anchors.fill: parent
             anchors.margins: 4
             color: wrapper.GridView.isCurrentItem ? "#009688" :"#3d3d3d"

             Text {
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 color: "white"
                 text: name
             }
         }

         MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onClicked: {
                gridView.currentIndex = index
             }
         }
       }
   }
 }
```

In Qt5, I set the z of the first MouseArea to -1, which can achieve the effect I want. But this method is invalid in Qt6 and cannot respond to the clicked event of the first MouseArea.
What should I do in Qt6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the weird places where `TapHandler` works better than `MouseArea`. By defining a `TapHandler` inside your `GridView` you will be notified when you are interacting in an area that's in your `GridView` but not on any of your `delegates`. I also move the `MouseArea` to inside your `Rectangle` so even the white edges between the `delegates` is now clicking thru to the `TapHandler`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { name: "Jim Williams" }
        ListElement { name: "John Brown" }
        ListElement { name: "Bill Smyth" }
        ListElement { name: "Sam Wise" }
    }
    
    GridView {
        id: gridView
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 80
        cellHeight: 80
        model: listModel
        TapHandler {
            onTapped: {
                console.log("out clicked!")
                gridView.currentIndex = -1
            }
        }
        delegate: Item {
            id: wrapper
            width: gridView.cellWidth
            height: gridView.cellHeight
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 4
                color: wrapper.GridView.isCurrentItem ? "#009688" :"#3d3d3d"
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "white"
                    text: name
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        gridView.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 0):

You can use just on mouse handler in the GridView and handle selections there. First you map the mouse position to the GridView coordinate system. Then you lookup the index at this position.

```
GridView {
    id: gridView
    anchors.fill: parent
    cellWidth: 80
    cellHeight: 80

    model: listModel

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: (mouse) => {
            console.log("grid clicked!");

            let posInGridView = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            let posInContentItem = mapToItem(gridView.contentItem, posInGridView)
            let index = gridView.indexAt(posInContentItem.x, posInContentItem.y)

            gridView.currentIndex = index;
        }
    }

    delegate: Item {
        id: wrapper
        width: gridView.cellWidth
        height: gridView.cellHeight

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 4
            color: wrapper.GridView.isCurrentItem ? "#009688" :"#3d3d3d"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "white"
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```